# vb.net winform from a usercontrol call a function on the parent form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-controls, raiseevent

I don't know how to put it right, but I have a vb.net winform app in which I want to use a customcontrol so I can re-use the logic on multiple forms. I know how to set values in this control from the parent (using properties in the control). But now I want to call a specifiek function on the parent form. Im my case LoadData() which is a procedure of the parentform. How can I do this?

I know I can reference the parent form by using Me.ParentForm in the usercontrol. But I cannot call the LoadData() procedure in the parentform.

Any help? This is a winforms app, not a ASP.NET app.

T.I.A.

[Edit]
I could solve my problem using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13529718/c-sharp-user-control-button-click-event-handler-to-call-a-function-from-main-for) example found right here. This is working fine

Comment: Try using MyBase.LoadData()

Answer (score 0):

First, a `UserControl` is for reusing *GUI* logic, so I hope that is what you meant.  If you are trying to reuse non-GUI logic you might want to create some stand-alone classes for that.

Second, it is generally bad design to call back up to the parent form in the way you describe because it makes the `UserControl` less reusable and it creates an overly tight binding between the two.  You should, if at all possible, push the data down into the `UserControl` instead.

If you can find no way for the Form to push the data down (perhaps because it is based upon a UI interaction within the `UserControl`), you have a couple of other options.  The first is to wrap up the data-loading behavior into an object that can be passed to the `UserControl` during initialization, and the the `UserControl` can access the `LoadData` method on it as needed.  Another approach is to have the UserControl define a set of Events that can be used to request external data from the form.  I like to use the "Query" prefix on these kinds of events.  So when a fetch button is tapped on your `UserControl`, it raises the "QueryData" event, and the form that is handling that event responds by populating a data container of some sort that is part of the custom `EventArgs`.

Either of these can be expanded upon if you need more assistance.

---

Upon re-reading the question, I it looks like perhaps my approach is over kill.  I was under the impression that the `LoadData` was a method in the Form that loaded data into the UserControl.  If it is just a simple call then focus on the event portion of my answer and ignore the data container portion.

Comment: Thx tcarvin, I do understand the reusing. That is why I use it. This control is used in a lot of my forms in this project. And the logici stays the same.

Comment: Sorry, was just making sure.  The rest of my answer applies to the UserControl though.  Let me know if there are any questions.

Answer (score 0):

I would add an event to your control and handle it on the form the control is part of.

In your control, put something like this:

```
Public Event LoadData(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
```

And in your form, you can have something like this:

```
Private Sub UserControl1_LoadData(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles UserControl1.LoadData
    '...Your code here
End Sub
```